# while merging bitbucket pull request with squash how to add PR owners name instead of merger?

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

In Bitbucket when any manager or lead merges the PR with squash merge it adds the merger name on the merge commit. instead, can we do some workaround or proper way so the PR owner name appears on code changes in blame history?

Comment: One simple option would be to _not_ squash.

Comment: @eftshift0 squash is mandatory in the organization, so that is not allowed for them.